# How can I select only the first occurrence of this class?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this markup.

```
<form>
  <fieldset id="step-1">
    <!-- form code-->
    <a class="previous"></a>
    <a class="next"></a>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="step-2">
    <!-- form code-->
    <a class="previous"></a>
    <a class="next"></a>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="step-3">
    <!-- form code-->
    <a class="previous"></a>
    <a class="next"></a>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

My jQuery

```
      $('.previous').on('click', function(evr) {
        evr.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest('fieldset').not('#step-1')){
          $(this).parent('fieldset').slideUp(function(){
            $(this).prev('fieldset').slideDown(); // this doesn't work
          });
        }
      });
      $('.next').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest('fieldset').not('#step-3')){
            $(this).closest('fieldset').slideUp();
            $(this).closest('fieldset').next('fieldset').slideDown();
        } 
        else if ($(this).closest('fieldset').is('#step-3')) {
          $('#step-3').slideUp();
        }
      });
```

I'm trying to create a multi-step modal where each fieldset will hide itself when you click the next button. The problem I'm having is the previous button. I can't seem to select the first fieldset from the second fieldset's previous button.

How can I select the previous fieldset? This should additionally work from #step-3, too.

Comment: try using `:first` selector in js

Comment: or `:eq(0)` , `.eq(0)` , `.first()`

Comment: this should have been very easy to research

Comment: `:first` won't work in my case. If I'm on step 3, pressing previous with the use of first will only make step 1 re-appear instead of step 2 since step 1 contains the first occurance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use first and last method and psudo selector in jquery

```
$('.previous').not(':first').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('fieldset').slideUp(function(){
       $(this).prev('fieldset').slideDown(); // this doesn't work
    });

  });
  $('.next').not(':last').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('fieldset').slideUp();
        $(this).closest('fieldset').next('fieldset').slideDown();
  });

$('.previous:first').click(function(e){
    console.log('first prev clicked');
});
$('.next:last').click(function(e){
    console.log('last next clicked');
     $('fieldset:last').slideUp();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:first`  selector with the class selector as like follows

```
$('.previous:first').on('click', function(evr) {
   alert("first");
});
$('.next:first').on('click', function(e){
   alert("nfirst");
});
```

Example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x3x0dr2x/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.first()` for selecting the first element of any class, where the class is assigned to multiple elements.

Check the usage manual [here](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

Comment: This would work fine but there are 3 steps. If i click the previous button from step 3, this will only make step 1 re-appear.